# Ignore null values while using .find()

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm using javascript's .find() method to search for values in my array. I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null` which is occurring at this line: `if (this.collection.find(x => x.details.numb.toUpperCase() === numb)) {`

I believe this error is happening because there are null values coming in at x.details.numb. Is it possible to ignore null values from within this line of code? Or will I have to remake my array without null values?

Comment: What's wrong with using `!= null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for null values before calling `toUpperCase`

```
if (this.collection.find(x => x.details && x.details.numb && x.details.numb.toUpperCase() === numb)) {
```

As @VLAZ pointed out in comments this will fail for `numb === ''` in that case you can use

```
(x.details && x.details.numb || '' ).toUpperCase() === numb
```

Comment: Problem with `numb === ""`

Comment: @VLAZ good catch thanks for pointing out mate !! we can use `(x.details && x.details.numb || '' ).toUpperCase() === numb` in that case

Comment: That sounds like a good compromise, to be honest. The only problem is if OP gets a zero or a `NaN` or something there, but I'd honestly not expect that. It seems like the expectation is for a string or `null`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was expecting a string or null, so this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sure !

```
x.details && x.details.numb && x.details.numb.toUpperCase() === numb
```

Comment: Problem with `numb === ""`

Comment: The original code doesn't specify what would happen if checking for empty string but would return the element if `x.details.numb = ""` and `numb = ""`. Your code would skip it.

Comment: That's what I have said yes.

Comment: The original code and your answer *behave differently*. You've purposefully made a semantic change to the code.

Comment: You don't know that @VLAZ, you just assume. Who told you that `numb` will be an empty string ? Maybe the OP doesn't care about that. I answer on what I see, not what I assume. Anyway, I made another answer to please you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a check for `null`, as well as `toUpperCase`:

```
this.colleciton.find(x => x.details != null && x.details.numb != null && x.details.numb.toUpperCase && x.details.numb.toUpperCase() === numb)
```

Comment: I'd check if `toUpperCase` is callable on `x.details.numb` (eg it's a `string`), otherwise it throws an error

Comment: @Honza if the *type* can be different, why not just check `typeof`? Or are you trying to make super sure somebody hasn't also tampered with the String prototype? If that's the case, how far do you go - what if somebody has made `x` a proxy or overriden the `find` method? How far down do you go?

Comment: @VLAZ that's what I mean by checking - `typeof` is imho enough. I'm not assuming altered prototypes, that's silly. Since this isn't Typescript and the definition is unclear, I'm just assuming `Cannot read property toUpperCase of undefined`. Now the answer is updated to take care of that

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in a condition, you can use `some` instead of `find`, because `some` stops once the condition is met (resulting in better performance) :

```
this.collection
  .some(item => item && item.details && items.details.numb.toUpperCase() === numb)
```

As brought up by a wild commenter, you can also prevent undefined values from happening as such :

```
this.collection
  .some(item => item 
    && item.details 
    && items.details.numb
    && ![undefined, null].includes(items.details.numb)
    items.details.numb.toUpperCase() === numb)
```

Comment: While `some` does offer a slight performance increase over `find`.  Its not because of the reason you state.  According to the MDN docs, "The find method executes the callback function once for each index of the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element.", thus `find` will also stops once the condition has been met.   But you are right that it does result in a faster execution most likely as just needs to return a simple boolean instead of the matching object.

Comment: @MichaelLynch thank you for the precision, I wasn't actually aware of that. Definitely worth noting !

Comment: Absolutely.  Wasn't aware of any performance difference between `some` and `find` until I saw your post, which lead me to do a little research into it.   I've always done `find` in the past, however i'm going to start using `some` now,  Thanks for the tip.